# How to set a inspected browser element as this

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, firefox, web-inspector

When inspecting an element in firefox, I would like to try `jquery` on it.

something like this

```
$(this).find('.myclass').first().val()
```

or whatever operations requires `$(this)`. By default a `this` refers to the window. Can I set `this` to a particular element in inspect mode with a trivial effort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an element is selected in the panel, typing in `$0` into the console will refer to that element. So you just need to replace `this` with `$0`:

```
$($0).find('.myclass').first().val()
```